# Can Custom Setters Break KVO Pattern? Break Retain or Copy Pattern?

Tags: objective-c, properties, key-value-observing

In Objective-C, I wonder whether a custom setter will override the KVO support (willChangeValueForKey: and didChangeValueForKey;) and do I need to include calls to these explicitly in the custom setter?

What about Retain and Copy? Would I need to explcitly include release and retain or copy in the setter for properties with Retain or Copy attributes (for non-ARC code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KVO will work automatically if your accessors are in the standard format (`-setFoo:` and `-foo`). Retain and copy, however, you will need to manage yourself in your custom accessors.

This is because retain and copy are part of the synthesized accessors, whereas KVO is based solely on method names. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172) for a full description of KVO-compliant method naming.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Apples Advanced memory management programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1) which tells you how to implement your own getters/setters properly:

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) state:

> Automatic support is provided by NSObject and is by default available for all properties of a class that are key-value coding
>   compliant. Typically, if you follow standard Cocoa coding and naming
>   conventions, you can use automatic change notifications—you don’t have
>   to write any additional code.

If you have a setter, just conform to the naming conventions.

Regarding copy/retain:

```
- (void)setFoo:(id)bar {
  @synchronized (self) { // synchronize if you have to, can be omitted in most cases
    if (bar_ != bar) { // bar_ is the ivar
      [bar_ release]; // omit in ARC
      bar_ = [bar copy]; // resp. retain in other variant
    }
  }
}
```

If your setter does not conform to the guildlines have a look at the "Manual Change Notification" section.